# Does Matplotlib support Qt5?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does Matplotlib support `Qt5`?

### Update:

Reading @tcaswell's answer and comments below, it looks like the `QT4Agg` targets `Qt4`, but that there is no backend that currently targets `Qt5`, is this correct? (e.g. it looks like [PyQt supports Qt5](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/pyqt-4101))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

matplotlib v1.4 and greater support Qt5 via the `Qt5Agg` backend.

---

The `*Agg` backends all use the Agg renderer for the drawing, the only difference in the gui UI they use.  The non-gui backends are used to generate files and can handle vector graphics just fine.  Excluding file limitations (not all formats support `alpha`) and bugs, all backends should be equally supported.

The `QT4Agg` backend targets QT4 and will work with either `PySide` or `PyQT` (which take care of the rest of the requirements).  The `QtAgg` backend targets QT3 and has been removed.

There is a PR (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3072) which adds support for Qt5 which has been merged.  Qt5 support for py3k will be in release 1.4.

Comment: Thanks so much tcaswell. What about Qt5? Is there a backend that targets it? Also, should I install PyQt before matplotlib if I want to eventually use it? Finally, is there any backend that ships with matplotlib? (the machine where I work only comes with GTK2)